# Limits and ordered sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

[image: Sequences]

I'm having trouble proving this for an arbitrary metric space. It's fairly simple in the R case but I'm unable to work out the trick needed for general cases.
I'd appreciate any help. The concept seems intuitive but tough to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $t \lt s$, then $A_t \cap B_s = \varnothing.$  Let $d(s, t)=2k$.  Then by the triangle inequality and trichotomy of total orders, $(A_t \cup B(t, k)) \cap (B_s \cup B(s, k))=\varnothing.$

But the left side is an open set containing $t$ so $\exists N_t \in \Bbb N~\forall n \gt N_t~(t_n \in A_t \cup B(t, k))$.  Similarly, the right-hand side is an open set containing $s$, so $\exists N_s \in \Bbb N~\forall n \gt N_s~(s_n \in B_s \cup B(s, k))$.

Choose $N= \max(N_t, N_s)$.  Then $n \gt N \Rightarrow t_n \lt s_n$, contradicting our assumption that $\forall n \in \Bbb N~(s_n \leq t_n)$.  Thus, it can't be the case that $t \lt s$, so it must be the case that $s \leq t$.

You need the assumption that you're working in a metric space (or some other separation axiom) to provide some kind of topological "separation" between $s$ and $t$.  Otherwise it's possible that every open set containing $s$ also contains $t$, or vice versa.